# Add Annotation in Google Chart with Vue Chartkick

Tags: vue.js, charts, google-visualization, chartkick

I want to add annotations to my column chart Google Chart, I use Vue Chartkick to display the chart. Is there any way for me to display Annotations from Vue Chartkick? Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

This is my chart:

```
<column-chart
        :data="data"
        legend="bottom"
        adapter="google"
      >
</column-chart>
```

And this is my data:

```
data: [
  {
    name: "Sales",
    data: {
      2021: 100,
      2020: 80,
      2019: 60,
      2018: 50,
    },
  },
],
```

Comment: is there documentation for Chartkick you can share?

Comment: This is the documentation for Vue Chartkick https://github.com/ankane/vue-chartkick @WhiteHat

Comment: to use an annotation, you have to be able to provide the column definition. in the docs, I only see a way to provide column values, not the column definition. maybe someone else knows...?